# Which of these database table structures is correct?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I am creating a small web app and am currently working on my database schema. I have two options for table structure but am not sure which is correct for relationships, appreciate advice?

**Option 1**

```
table1
  - id (int) [auto increment, pk]
  - name (varchar)

table2
  - id (int) [auto increment, pk]
  - name (varchar)
  - table1Id (int) [fk on table1.id]
```

**Option 2**

```
table1
  - id (int) [auto increment, pk, fk on table3.table1Id]
  - name (varchar)

table2
  - id (int) [auto increment, pk, fk on table3.table2Id]
  - name (varchar)

table3
  - table1Id (int) [pk]
  - table2Id (int [pk]
```

Appreciate people's thoughts.

**EDIT - Worked example:**

```
tblCountries
  - id (int) [auto increment, pk]
  - name (varchar)

tblCities
  - id (int) [auto increment, pk]
  - name (varchar)
```

My query would pull a city and then need the corresponding country.

Comment: Question is - can there be 1:M or N:M relationship in the data. That is the factor which decides which of the two are correct.

Comment: each is correct depending on what you are trying to do.  however, you don't say what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, am a relative newbie here. There will be a 1 to many relationship (1 item in table1 can have multiple in table2). My queries will reference the item in table2 and want to pull back the corresponding item from table1.

Would it be easier if I posted a better example?

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer depends on how you want to handle cities that are split in two countries.  Like the old east/west Germany Berlin, can it be in two countries at one time? if so, you must go with option 2. so the same city row can be associated with two different countries.

I can't really find any cities split into two countries (tried google). So, I would ignore the split city case and just go with option 1.

I prefer CityID, CityName, CountryID and CountryName over just ID and Name.  if you need to search code, it is impossible if you just use Name and ID to find anything.   This really depends on how you are accessing your database.  If you are using OOP and/or some frameworks, then using "ID" and "Name" for properties makes more sense.  If you are writing procedures and straight queries, then "xxxxID" and "xxxxxName" would be better. Whatever you pick, stay consistent.

Comment: Thanks KM. Appreciate the info.